# Regex password checker

Tags: c#, regex, security, passwords

I am creating some regex code so I can check passwords when a customer is trying to create a account. Currently I have two pieces of code that seem to work when tested on :- http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html.

The first bit is:

```
^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$
```

This makes sure:

- Password is 8 digits long
- Contains at least one one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character

The second part is:

```
\S*(.)\1{3,}\S*
```

This makes sure:

Any 4 or more consecutive identical characters are matched.

The question is, how can I combine them both? I have tried to no avail but they seem to be working fine seperatly.

Thanks

Comment: Read: http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: First off, you should note that those (?=) lookaheads don't work in Internet Explorer's Javascript due to a regex bug: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug and http://regexadvice.com/blogs/mash/archive/2009/02/21/Looking-again-at-the-Lookahead-bug.aspx

Comment: Any reason not to check them separately? In general I would probably prefer to do several simpler checks rather than one massive one. That way when you come back to look at it later or another developer comes to look at it then it will be obvious what its doing. I would be very surprised if you are seeing a performance issue due to useing two regex instead of one...

Comment: @AricTenEyck Anyone relying on JavaScript to validate input should have their programming license revoked. This is tagged c#, so I bet the OP is using C# for validation.

Comment: @AricTenEyck this post is tagged with C#, not JavaScript

Comment: @Chris - There will probably not be much (if any) performance increase. I personally just prefere doing it in one go rather than have several calls.

Comment: In response to your edit I'm really not sure that it looks like it should work. The first bracketed section for example seems to check if it has a number from 0-8. Does it work if your only number is a 9? Oh, and it doesn't check for repeating characters. So its basically a broken version of your first one which I assume is why he deleted it.

Comment: I have tested it. Out of all 7 tests (different variations of passwords, all uppercase, no numbers etc..) it passed them all.

Comment: Looking into it closer, there is a error. You are correct sir :)!

Comment: Did you try "9abjkjashdkjh&aA" This should pass I believe. And "8888888abjkjashdkjh&aA" should fail but doesn't because that test in the edit doesn't even try to deal with repeat characters. The first group checks for a digit from 0-8. The second group checks for lower case. The third group checks for upper case and the fourth group checks for punctuation. The last unbracketed part checks for length of 8 or more. You don't need to run tests to prove it failed, you can just look at and understand the regex. And this is exactly why breaking it down makes it better. :)

Comment: I done similar and after that I realised I was reading the results incorrectly. This is my first afternoon playing with regex so still trying to get used to it. Think I just shot the gun thinking it was working (more hoping it was working :))

Comment: Some things about regex: they are very powerful, very unreadable and not for every purpose. Regex handlers are not all created equal either. It's much much better to create small regexps and link them together. Of course, you want to avoid mistakes, so create a set of tests (using a a live regex evaluator). Finally, comment the hell out of them because the next sod (e.g. you in a few years) will use more time to understand them all then it costs you to create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just run two separate tests? The regex patterns above are complicated enough. Keeping them separate will make the code more understandable and will also give you the flexibility to add/remove additional tests without touching a pattern that is already working. Also, depending on which test fails, you can provide the user with a more detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I have taken this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to considering allowing passwords greater then at least 12 characters.  Do yourself a favor and your customer's a favor and allow a customer to use any size password greater then 12 characters.  Anything less then 12 is extremely easy to brute foce.

As to your question I will let somebody else answer that.

Comment: a) that should be a comment (the clue being when in your answer you say that it is not an answer) b) his current regex does seem to allow passwords longer than 8 characters.

Comment: They could have a password of 255 characters if they wish. The requirements are not mine, it is to adhere to ISO27001.

Comment: @Chris - What I had to say was to long for a comment.  The way the question was worded made it appear the regular expresion was to limit the passwords to 8 characters.  I didn't duplicate the same reg expression for a reason, 3 people commented, but the point of 8 characters being to short is valid.

Comment: Your response was 325 characters long, not too long for a comment at all. And although I can see how there could be some ambiguity and whatever the merit of saying that passwords shouldn't be restircted in length it was still not an answer to the question and shouldn't therefore have been put in as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply combine that second regex to the first one, you'll be requiring all passwords to contain four consecutive, identical characters, and I'm pretty sure you want to *forbid* that.  Try this:

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?:(.)(?!\1{3}))+$
```

The last group captures one character at a time, doing a negative lookahead each time to make sure it isn't followed by three more of the same character.  Notice that I removed the `.*` from the beginning of your first regex.  That never belonged there, though it wasn't really hurting anything before.  But in this regex the final group has to be the only part that consumes characters, or it doesn't do any good.